# Can Webpack replace Gulp?

Tags: gulp, webpack

So I am transitioning to Webpack from Gulp. Can I still watch for changes and for instance minify images e.g. in app/images/**/*.{svg,etc}?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. If you're using Webpack, there is no reason to manage any assets with Gulp. Suggested reading: [Webpack, when to use and why](http://blog.andrewray.me/webpack-when-to-use-and-why/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use webpack with gulp https://webpack.js.org/guides/integrations/#gulp